# How to draw UML 2.0 notation diagram with template for visio 2010

Tags: uml, visio, use-case, system-analysis

I want to model to a system with UML 2.0 diagram especially with Use case diagram. Visio 2010 only support UML 1.0 notaion. So how can I get UML 2.0 template for Microsoft visio 2010.

Thank you everyone for helping this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a UML too? You could still do the drawings, but you would also comply with the spec (by the way, UML 2.5 is the current release).
I would suggest Eclipse Papyrus: It's free and supports the whole UML spec.

Comment: Yes sir, I should use UML 2.5 for update use. I will check your recommended tool. But if you have any idea with MS Visio 2010 for above question. Thank you for your answer.